# Why do I get inconsistent results from an indexOf action in Google Scripts on what appear to be the exact same inputs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

I have tried to find a way to search an array within a Google script but I have been unable to find anything that will work. My end game is to essentially do a vlookup on a number of arrays in a Google Sheet, perform functions on them, and push them into another array to be pasted for analysis. I have approximately 2,500 loops I'll need to do so I am trying to avoid reading/writing as much as possible. This is an extremely simple version of my main obstacle.

When I look for the index of number in an array, I am unable to get anything other than -1 unless I am looking for a subset of that array. When I look for an exact replica of a different array or when I hard code it, I am not getting consistent results. Thank you in advance for your help and patience!

This is a link to my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qwIk9iqEkQz9fl1kSAnQ9XMWuZ3S_9jSOxfoNH4P2R8/edit?usp=sharing) and here is an image for a quick reference:

[image: quick view of my sheet]

This is the code I am trying to use showing that I get different indexes on what I think should be the same result:

```
    function indexOfTest() {

  //Set sheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  //Get ranges
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange("A1:B7").getValues(); //data set of the locations I want to search eventually
  var findRange = dataSheet.getRange("E3:E4").getValues(); //values I want to find the row of in the data set (would change in the spreadsheet based on the user's inputs)
  var locationRange = dataSheet.getRange(1,1,dataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //smaller range of the locations I want to locate (1st column) 

  //test showing that indexOf works when I search for a subset of the array within the array
  var findTest1 = locationRange[2]; //set variable to a subset of the array I will search
  var searchResult1 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest1); //finding the index of the subset of the array within the array

  //test showing that indexOf does NOT work when I search for the exact same value in the same array  
  var findTest2 = findRange[0]; //set variable to the the user-entered cell on the sheet which is exactly the same as the subset of the array from the first test
  var searchResult2 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest2); //this comes back as -1 for some reason 

  //test showing that I can't even find it when I hard code it to exactly the same as somethng in the array that I was able to find earlier  
  var findTest3 = [13]; //hardcoded variable to exactly the same as the subset of the array from the first test
  var searchResult3 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest3); //this comes back as -1 for some reason 

  var x = 1 // this is where I have the debug spot (x = 1 is meaningless but wanted the debugger to stop here) 
  // why does the indexOf function work for the first test but not the other two?!?!?!?
  // any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

}
```

When I look at the debugger, I don't understand why I get -1 on two of the tests but it works on one... and they are searching for the exact same thing!

[image: Debugger showing different results for same funciton]

Please and thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

**Value retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array.**

This is a very important point for your situation.

### 1. Preparation

As a preparation, it confirms the values of`dataRange`, `findRange`, `locationRange`, `findTest1`, `findTest2` and `findTest3`.

When `dataRange`, `findRange` and `locationRange` are retrieved, those are as follows.

```
dataRange = [["Location #","State"],[11,"AK"],[13,"NE"],[17,"FL"],[24,"IL"],[47,"IL"],[69,"NV"]]
findRange = [[13],["State"]]
locationRange = [["Location #"],[11],[13],[17],[24],[47],[69]]
```

And `findTest1`, `findTest2` and `findTest3` are `[13]`.

### 2. Experiment

Here, it thinks of about 3 patterns which search using `findTest1`, `findTest2` and `findTest3`.

#### Pattern 1

```
var findTest1 = locationRange[2];
var searchResult1 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest1);
```

In this case, from `[13]` is searched from `[["Location #"],[11],[13],[17],[24],[47],[69]]` which is `locationRange`. But `findTest1` is in `locationRange`. This works. I think because `indexOf()` might refer the pointer from the same array using the element in the same array. As an other sample, please see the following sample script.

```
var ar = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var r1 = ar.indexOf([4, 5, 6]); // -1
var r2 = ar.indexOf(ar[2]); // 2
```

In this script, `indexOf()` can be used using the element in the same 2 dimensional array. At `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, when the value for searching is an array, the pointer might be referred. This result is new discovery for me.

#### Pattern 2

```
var findTest2 = findRange[0];
var searchResult2 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest2);
```

In this case, from `[13]` is searched from `[["Location #"],[11],[13],[17],[24],[47],[69]]` which is `locationRange`. But `findTest2` is NOT in `locationRange`. By this, `indexOf()` tries to search as a value. But it doesn't work because of 2 dimensional array. And if the pointer is searched using `[13]`, also it is not found, because `[13]` is not the element in `locationRange`.

#### Pattern 3

```
var findTest3 = [13];
var searchResult3 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest3);
```

In this case, the situation is the same with pattern 2.

### 3. Modified script

If you want to search `13` from `locationRange`, I think that in your case, the following modification can be used. In this modified script, `searchResult1`, `searchResult2` and `searchResult3` are `2`.

```
function indexOfTest2() {
  //Set sheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  //Get ranges
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange("A1:B7").getValues(); //data set of the locations I want to search eventually
  var findRange = dataSheet.getRange("E3:E4").getValues(); //values I want to find the row of in the data set (would change in the spreadsheet based on the user's inputs)
  var locationRange = dataSheet.getRange(1,1,dataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //smaller range of the locations I want to locate (1st column) 

  // Below script was modified.
  locationRange = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], locationRange);
  var findTest1 = locationRange[2];
  var searchResult1 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest1);
  var findTest2 = findRange[0][0];
  var searchResult2 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest2);
  var findTest3 = [13][0];
  var searchResult3 = locationRange.indexOf(findTest3);
}
```

#### Note :

- `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], locationRange)` converts 2 dimensional array of `[["Location #","State"],[11,"AK"],[13,"NE"],[17,"FL"],[24,"IL"],[47,"IL"],[69,"NV"]]` to 1 dimensional array of `["Location #",11,13,17,24,47,69]`.
- At `findTest1`, `locationRange[2]` is used because `locationRange` is 1 dimensional array.
- At `findTest2`, `var findTest2 = findRange[0][0]` is used because `findRange` is 2 dimensional array.
- At `findTest3`, `var findTest3 = [13][0]` is used because it retrieves `13` from `[13]`.

### 4. References :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: I think converting it to a 1D array will get me where I need to go. Thanks so much for your help and have a great day!

Comment: @Jim P Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Per the JavaScript spec, [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) uses [strict equality comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6):

> `indexOf()` compares `searchElement` to elements of the `Array` using strict equality (the same method used by the `===` or triple-equals operator).

Strict equality, in the terms of `Object`s of same type, means that Object A must be the exact same object reference as Object B for `A === B` to be `true`. Two objects having the same values does not mean they have the same object reference:

```
var A = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var B = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
Logger.log(A === B) // false
B = A;
Logger.log(A === B) // true
B = A.slice(0);
Logger.log(A === B) // false
Logger.log(A.map(function (ai, i) { return ai === B[i]; })); // true, true, true
```

In more recent JS versions you can use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to perform a values-based comparison. However, Apps Script is only JS 1.6 (with some bells + whistles), but `includes` is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunatley I am stuck using Apps Script so I will convert to a 1D array as mentioned in the other answer but this is great to know. Have a great one and thanks again!